# wkhtmltopdf with wicked_pdf issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf(0.10.0 rc2) and wicked_pdf(0.9.9) for generating pdf report.
While running i got the following error.

```
RuntimeError (Error: Failed to execute:
["/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf", "-q", "--page-size", "A4", "--margin-top", "5", "--margin-bottom", "10", "--margin-left", "5", "--margin-right", "5", "file:////tmp/[\"wicked_pdf\", \".html\"]21873-0", "/tmp/[\"wicked_pdf_generated_file\", \".pdf\"]21873-0"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: Error: Failed loading page file:////tmp/["wicked_pdf", ".html"]21873-0 (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
)
```

my controller are:

```
render :pdf => "#{@note_name}",:layout => '/layouts/pdf_template.html.erb', :template=>'pdf/financial/maintenance_exp/maintenance_exp_pdf.html.erb'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

FYI:when I do 
:show_as_html=>true
 its not throwing any error.its rendering the html in browser.

Answer (score 2):

Similar error, i was trying to use `WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_html_file`

I ended up using `WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string` with following helper to generate rendered html string:

```
  def pdf_html
    ApplicationController.renderer.new.render(
      template: 'purchase_orders/pdf.html.erb',
      layout: 'layouts/pdf_layout.html.erb',
      locals: { abc: 'xyz' },
      formats: [:html]
    )
  end
```

*Obviously assumes ApplicationController is present*

My rails version: `6.0.1`

Might help other searching for similar errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and fixed it by following directions here

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/157

Namely I switched to temporary fix of gem by changing `gemfile` entry to:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf', github: 'mileszs/wicked_pdf'
```

But note that in my case the issue was file locations on windows having file:// instead of file:/// -- so it may not help you.  On the other hand, it was the same error message so maybe worth a shot.

Comment: This worked at the time question was posted, not a solution now(for people still searching this error) See my answer here for what worked for me.